# Vertica S3 Export - Order of the columns in the exported file

Tags: amazon-s3, vertica, data-files

I am using Vertica S3 Export function to dump the table data into multiple files on S3.
As I need the complete table, I just pass * to the function instead of the column names (also it would be tedious to give the column list, count is 100 +)

I am not quite sure on the order of the columns in the files that are created on S3. Files doesn't include any header information.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM your_table;` is - by standard - equivalent to `SELECT first_column, second_column,third_column FROM your_table;` that is, always in the order of the columns in the table and the entries of the table in the database catalog.

So you can rely on the fact that they will be in the same order as in the table.